# client app not found angular universal when adding

Tags: angular, angular-universal

I'm using this Angular to universal SSR but the project angular version is 7, i am adding SSR to existing solution but not still geting this error "Client app xxx not found."....

ng add @nguniversal/express-engine --clientProject angular.io-example

Comment: Did you make sure to use the app name specified in `angular.json` file?

Comment: Yeah i did it correct... still getting same error. but when do it in angular 8 that working fine

Answer (score 1):

Check the angular.json file under `projects.${your project name}`. This happened to me when I cloned the repo from GitHub.